# Chemfig double bonds have inconsistant appearance

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I have drawn the molecule meso-Tetraphenylporphyrin using the following Chemfig code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\setchemfig{%
    atom sep = 1.75em,
    stack sep = 0.3em,
    bond offset = 1.25pt,
    double bond sep = .25em,
}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{[:-90](=_[::-120]*5(-N(-H)-(=(-[4]Ph)-[::-48]*5(=[,,,1]N-[,,1](=(-[2]Ph)-[:-30])-=-))-=-))(-[6]Ph)-[::120]*5(-=-(=^(-[8]Ph)-[::48]*5(=-=?-N(-H)-))-N=)}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following output (red boxes added with Snipping Tool):

[image]

Notice how the highlighted bonds appear different, despite being the exact same types of bonds. I would prefer all junctions like this to appear like the highlighted bond on the right. What in my code is causing this inconsistant behavior?

Comment: Welcome! Could be a very good first question if you add to your code the minimum needed parts (preamble, begin...end document),  etc. so that it can be compiled  "as is". Help us to help you!

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the code to include those things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "_" to put all double bonds "inside" of the big ring

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\setchemfig{%
    atom sep = 1.75em,
    stack sep = 0.3em,
    bond offset = 1.25pt,
    double bond sep = .25em,
}
\chemfig{[:-90](=_[::-120]*5(-N(-H)-(=_(-[4]Ph)-[::-48]*5(=[,,,1]N-[,,1](=_(-[2]Ph)-[:-30])-=-))-=-))(-[6]Ph)-[::120]*5(-=-(=^(-[8]Ph)-[::48]*5(=-=?-N(-H)-))-N=)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\catcode`\_=11
\tikzset{
    mydb/.style args={#1}{
        decoration={%
            markings,
            mark=at position 0 with {
                \coordinate (CF@startdeloc) at (0,\dimexpr#1\CF_doublesep);
            },
            mark=at position 1 with {
                \coordinate (CF@enddeloc) at (0,\dimexpr#1\CF_doublesep);
                \draw[red,shorten <=\CF_doublesep/1.75,shorten >=\CF_doublesep/1.7] (CF@startdeloc)--(CF@enddeloc);
            }
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
}
\catcode`\_=8
\begin{document}
    \setchemfig{%
        atom sep = 1.75em,
        stack sep = 0.3em,
        bond offset = 1.25pt,
        double bond sep = .25em,
    }
    \chemfig{[:-90](=_[::-120]*5(-N(-H)-(-[,,,,mydb={-}](-[4]Ph)-[::-48]*5(=[,,,1]N-[,,1](=(-[2]Ph)-[:-30])-=-))-=-))(-[6]Ph)-[::120]*5(-=-(=^(-[8]Ph)-[::48]*5(=-=?-N(-H)-))-N=)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\catcode`\_=11
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\dbsep}{\CF_doublesep}
\tikzset{
    mydb/.style args={#1}{
        decoration={%
            markings,
            mark=at position 0 with {
                \coordinate (CF@startdeloc) at (0,#1\dbsep);
            },
            mark=at position 1 with {
                \coordinate (CF@enddeloc) at (0,#1\dbsep);
                \draw[shorten <=\dbsep/1.75,shorten >=\dbsep/1.75] (CF@startdeloc)--(CF@enddeloc);
            }
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
}
\catcode`\_=8
\begin{document}
    \setchemfig{%
        atom sep = 1.75em,
        stack sep = 0.3em,
        bond offset = 1.25pt,
        double bond sep = .25em,
    }
    \chemfig{[:-90](-[::-120,,,,mydb={-}]*5(-N(-H)-(-[,,,,mydb={-}](-[4]Ph)-[::-48]*5(=[,,,1]N-[,,1](-[,,,,mydb={-}](-[2]Ph)-[:-30])-=-))-=-))(-[6]Ph)-[::120]*5(-=-(-[,,,,mydb={+}](-[8]Ph)-[::48]*5(=-=?-N(-H)-))-N=)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, but now the red line is somewhat shorter than its counterpart on the right side, isn't it?

Comment: @Jasper Habicht Yes, I only changed the red line.